# Set Created By value in Sitecore

Tags: c#, .net, content-management-system, sitecore

Is there any way we can set values of `Created By` or `Created Date` item fields in **Sitecore** from code behind?

Thanks

Comment: Why -1 for this question?

Comment: And why 3 votes to close? I don't understand, either...

Comment: 'Closed as too localized' absolute nonsense. This is moderation gone too far.  This is a perfectly valid question.

Comment: While the question lacks detail, it is still valid IMO and has my vote to reopen.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just update it using the item's fields, for example:

```
using (new Sitecore.SecurityModel.SecurityDisabler())
{
    item.Editing.BeginEdit();
    item[Sitecore.FieldIDs.Created] = Sitecore.DateUtil.ToIsoDate(DateTime.Now);
    item.Editing.EndEdit();
}
```

Comment: Exactly. And `Sitecore.FieldIDs.CreatedBy` in the same way. +1

Comment: @MarekMusielak thanks for that. When setting CreatedBy, how do you specify a certain user?

Comment: E.g. item[Sitecore.FieldIDs.CreatedBy] = "sitecore\\admin";